# How to create a dictionary of items in a specific format?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list in python called itemList which contains data as the following:

```
itemList = [Soil, Temperature, Humidity,...]
```

I want to store this information from the list into a dictionary in the following format:

```
{
   "Characteristic": "Soil",
   "Info": "ToRead"
},
{
   "Characteristic": "Temperature",
   "Info": "ToRead"
},
...
```

The "Info" field is fixed in all of the {}. I was not sure on how to create this structure. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: I highly recommend to use any of the list-comprehension based solutions provided instead of the for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `dictList = [{"Characteristic": item, "Info": "ToRead"} for item in itemList]`

A list comprehension that iterates over the item list and creates the desired dict for each item. Simple, one-liner, pythonic, explicit, not much more to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `dict` inside a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
itemList = ["Soil", "Temperature", "Humidity"]
result = [dict(Characteristic=i, Info="ToRead") for i in itemList]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Characteristic': 'Soil', 'Info': 'ToRead'},
 {'Characteristic': 'Temperature', 'Info': 'ToRead'},
 {'Characteristic': 'Humidity', 'Info': 'ToRead'}]
```

Comment: Dict literals are also valid, no need to use the constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a list of dicts it's easily done with a for loop.

```
itemList = ['Soil', 'Temperature', 'Humidity']
output = []
for item in itemList:
    output.append({'Characteristic': item, 'Info': 'ToRead'})
```

Now output should contain a list of dicts:

```
[{'Characteristic': 'Soil', 'Info': 'ToRead'}, {'Characteristic': 'Temperature', 'Info': 'ToRead'}, {'Characteristic': 'Humidity', 'Info': 'ToRead'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list-comprehension with nested dictionary literals to create the data...

```
>>> itemList = ["Soil", "Temperature", "Humidity"]                          
>>> d = [{"Characteristic": c, "Info": "ToRead"} for c in itemList]        
>>> d                                                                      
[{'Characteristic': 'Soil', 'Info': 'ToRead'},
 {'Characteristic': 'Temperature', 'Info': 'ToRead'},
 {'Characteristic': 'Humidity', 'Info': 'ToRead'}]
```

... then use [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html#json.dump) or `dumps` to dump it to a file or pretty-print it.

```
>>> import json                                                            
>>> print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))                                         
[
  {
    "Characteristic": "Soil",
    "Info": "ToRead"
  },
  {
    "Characteristic": "Temperature",
    "Info": "ToRead"
  },
  {
    "Characteristic": "Humidity",
    "Info": "ToRead"
  }
]
```

Comment: @Adirio Okay, strictly speaking its a list comprehension with dict literals inside, not a mixed list and dict copmrehension. And in your world this is worth a downvote?

Comment: @Adirio This implies that by just commenting on this minor issue I would not have fixed it. IMHO, downvotes should be reserved for answers that are factually wrong (in a way that matters) or otherwise not helpful, e.g. missing the actual problem.

Comment: You can use the downvote tool however you wish, but using it a pressure tool to make others correct their answer seems completely legit to me. And you answer was factually wrong, the importance of the mistake is then subjetive.

Answer (score 0):

```
itemList = ['Soil', 'Temperature', 'Humidity']

data = []


for item in itemList:
    data.append({
        "Characteristic": item,
        "Info": "ToRead"
    })

print(str(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
dicts = []
for item in itemList[:]:
    newDict = {"Item:item, "Info":"toRead"}
    dicts.append(newDict)
```

I hope this helps, and that I didn't misinterpret the problem! I'm assuming the format you presented was a list of dictionaries.